# Validations for rows and columns in the csv file matching with mysql databse fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i did the task of importing csv file to MySql databse. But now my requirements are:
1. Rows and columns of csv file should match with rows and columns of MySql database such that if any row or column is missing, it should raise an error: "Missing @row1 or column 2"..
2. In my code, table header i.e. name, location, city etc; headings are often repeating on every import.

My code as follows:

```
def load_csv

end

 def import_csv
csv=params[:file].read
n=0
parsed_file = CSV.parse(csv)
parsed_file.each  do |row|
i=User.new
i.name = row[0]
i.location = row[1]
i.city = row[2]
if i.valid?
i.save
n=n+1
GC.start if n%50==0
flash[:notice] = "CSV Imported Successfully, with  #{n} records"                                
end
end
```

In views:

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => import_csv_user_path,  :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
 <table>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="dump_file">
Select a CSV File :
</label>
</td>
<td ><%= file_field_tag :file -%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='2'><%= submit_tag 'Submit' -%></td>
</tr>
</table>
<% end -%>
```

Please help me out......

Comment: This you code, empty load_csv method?

Answer (score -1):

I have done the same job with your current one. however I don't think it's a very good/straight forward/concise/elegant solution to do this, since this( validate the CSV file ) is not a very good requirement, for me it's the same as "version control" for databases/models.  It may mess all your code up, especially for those people who is not an expert.

OK, complaint done.  let me share my solution:

1. via javascript.  I haven't implemented it in this way, however comparing what I have done, I prefer this way. steps are:

   1. read local csv file( refer to jasmine's approach to load test fixture).
   2. validate the columns between csv and database table's.
   3. show result. if not pass, give user warning message.
2. via ruby code in remote: I did it in this way , and found it not very good ( maybe I used many js functions.... dirty, not elegant, hard to test, slow to response, ajax... etc) If you do so, just use plain html pages, not "dialog", or "modal window" please.

   1. update file to remote server.
   2. validate the csv file in remote server.
   3. give user warning message if validation failed.

Comment: OK. What you meant to say is, the coding that i have done doesn't match my requirements.. I am new to Ruby on Rails. Can you please guide me to the right path by providing any interesting links or how can i modify my code??..